# Can't get data from JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
var obj = [];
$('#next').click(function(){
  jQuery.getJSON(produk1 , function(product1) {
    hargana1 = product1.price;
    obj.push({
       harga: hargana1
    });
  }

  jQuery.getJSON(produk2 , function(product1) {
    hargana2 = product2.price;
    obj.push({
       harga: hargana2
    });
  }

  console.log(harga)
});
```

And I have result on my console like this

[image: console]

How can I get value from harga?
I try with `obj['harga']` It shows undefined

Comment: That's an array, not object. Try `obj[0].harga`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can't access JavaScript array values by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038768/cant-access-javascript-array-values-by-index)

Comment: It's showing `Cannot read property 'harga' of undefined` when I try to obj.lenght, it's showing undefined, I think I have weird format of my array

Answer (score 2):

Well if you take a closer look then you will see that this is actually an array filled with objects. you can see that its an array by the brackets `[]`

Try it like this: `obj[0].harga`

Comment: It's showing `Cannot read property 'harga' of undefined` when I try to obj.lenght, it's showing undefined, I think I have weird format of my array

Comment: could you show us some code? with just the data i can not help you

Answer (score 1):

You should iterate through the array :

```js
const out = [{harga:21132424},{harga:543535}]
console.log(out)

out.forEach(obj=>{
     const harga = obj.harga;
     //do something to harga here
     console.log(harga)
})
```